# Check if no arguments passed

Tags: ruby, arguments

Here's some code:

```
$ cat 1.rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def f p1 = nil
    unless p1   # TODO
        puts 'no parameters passed'
    end
end
f
f nil
$ ./1.rb
no parameters passed
no parameters passed
```

The question is, is there a way to distinguish between no arguments and one `nil` argument passed?

**UPD**

I decided to add a use case in `javascript` to make things hopefully clearer:

```
someProp: function(value) {
    if (arguments.length) {
        this._someProp = value;
    }
    return this._someProp;
}
```

Comment: If p1 is defaulting to nil, isn't passing nil the same as not?

Comment: @Cereal Please take a look at the question, I added a use case. So, if I can't distinguish between no value and `nil`, I can't set variable's value to `nil`. One could argue that I should choose different default value then, but I believe `nil` is the most appropriate value in this case. Also, it might be that you can't expect variable to not take some value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three ways in general use. One way is to use the default value to set another variable indicating whether or not the default value was evaluated:

```
def f(p1 = (no_argument_passed = true; nil))
  'no arguments passed' if no_argument_passed
end

f      # => 'no arguments passed'
f(nil) # => nil
```

The second way is to use some object that is only known inside the method as default value, so that it is impossible for an outsider to pass that object in:

```
-> {
  undefined = BasicObject.new
  define_method(:f) do |p1 = undefined|
    'no arguments passed' if undefined.equal?(p1)
  end
}.()

f      # => 'no arguments passed'
f(nil) # => nil
```

Of these two, the first one is more idiomatic. The second one (actually, a variation of it) is used inside Rubinius, but I have never encountered it anywhere else.

A third solution would be to take a variable number of arguments using a splat:

```
def f(*ps)
  num_args = ps.size
  raise ArgumentError, "wrong number of arguments (#{num_args} for 0..1)" if num_args > 1
  'no arguments passed' if num_args.zero?
end

f      # => 'no arguments passed'
f(nil) # => nil
```

Note that this requires you to re-implement Ruby's arity checking by hand. (And we still haven't gotten it right, because this raises the exception *inside* the method, whereas Ruby would raise it at the *call site*.) It also requires you to manually document your method signature because automated documentation generators such as RDoc or YARD will infer an arbitrary number of parameters instead of a single optional one.

Comment: The first way reminds me of `lisp`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Well, I was probably wrong, it reminded me the way to determine if an argument is supplied: `(defun foo (a b &optional (c 3 c-supplied-p)) (list a b c c-supplied-p))`. `(foo 1 2)   ==> (1 2 3 NIL)`, `(foo 1 2 3) ==> (1 2 3 T)`, `(foo 1 2 4) ==> (1 2 4 T)`.

Answer (score 5):

You could request for splat arguments:

```
def f(*args)
  if args.empty?
    puts 'no parameters passed'
  else
    p1 = args[0]
    ...
  end
end
```

Some other option might be to have a private object to indicate no parameter passed:

```
def initialize
  @no_param_passed = Object.new
end

def f(p1 = @no_param_passed)
  if p1 == @no_param_passed
    puts 'no parameters passed'
  end
end
```